# Getting object object in a custom gutenberg block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a question. I am new and still learning :)

I want to create a review block with gutenberg. And the rating has to be stars. But for some reason i dont get it worked. Maybe i am doing it wrong, maybe it isn't possible. I hope some on could explain it to me.

For now i have created a selectcontrol and this works. When selecting A i get A. But i want to replace value: A for a star:

What i have

> ```
> <SelectControl
>   multiple
>   label={ __( 'Select some users:' ) }
>   value={ testimonial.selectcontrol } // e.g: value = [ 'a', 'c' ]
>   onChange={ (value) => handleTestimonialChange('selectcontrol', value, index ) }
>   options={ [
>    { value: null, label: 'Select a User', disabled: true },
>    { value: 'a', label: 'User A' },
>    { value: 'b', label: 'User B' },
>    { value: 'c', label: 'User c' },
>     ] }
> />
> ```

What i want

> ```
> <SelectControl
>   multiple
>   label={ __( 'Select some users:' ) }
>   value={ testimonial.selectcontrol } // e.g: value = [ 'a', 'c' ]
>   onChange={ (value) => handleTestimonialChange('selectcontrol', value, index ) }
>   options={ [
>    { value: null, label: 'Select a User', disabled: true },
>    { value: <i class="fas fa-star"></i>, label: 'User A' },
>    { value: 'b', label: 'User B' },
>    { value: 'c', label: 'User c' },
>     ] }
> />
> ```

The value returns in this code:

> selectcontrolDisplay =props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
> return <span key={ index }>{testimonial.selectcontrol};
> } );

What i get back in the backed from Wordpress is object object. Like mentiond above, i am not sure or it possible. If some on could explain something different with the same result. I am happy to.

If the full code is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are getting `[object object]` is that in JSX `<i class="fas fa-star"></i>` gets converted into a React component (an object). So in your `onChange={ (value) => {...} }` line, `value` is a React component (an object) *not* the HTML you want to output. I would suggest using some other identifier as your option value (e.g. a string) and then converting that into your star icon when rendering:

```js
props.attributes.testimonial.map((testimonial, index) => {
  return (testimonial.selectcontrol === 'star')
    ? <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    : testimonial.selectcontrol;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for time and answer! i got it work with a minor change where i changed '===' to '=='.

 selectcontrolDisplay = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
              return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') ? <i class="fas fa-star"></i> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
         } );

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for time and answer! i got it work with a minor change where i changed '===' to '=='.

```
  selectcontrolDisplay = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
   return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') ? <i class="fas fa-star"></i> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
   } );
```